# Display none in child element when clicking button - React

Tags: reactjs, events

How can I, when clicking on the button, display none in the Test components.

```
function Teste({testeA,testeB}) {

    return <div> {testeA} - {testeB} </div> 
}

export default function Simulacao() {
 
    return <>
            <button onClick=""/>
            <Teste testeA="aaa" testeB="bbb"/>
            <Teste testeA="ccc" testeB="ddd"/>
        </>
}
```

I understand the concept of building components in React and reusing them, but I'm having difficulty working with events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to do as below if you want to use CSS to hide them. You could also return `<></>` if `show` is false:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Teste({ testeA, testeB, show = true }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: show ? "block" : "none" }}>
      {testeA} - {testeB}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Simulacao() {
  const [showTeste, setShowTeste] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowTeste((showTeste) => !showTeste);
        }}
      >
        Toggle
      </button>
      <Teste testeA="aaa" testeB="bbb" show={showTeste} />
    </>
  );
}
```